# Comparison test of convergence or divergence of Harmonic series

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Is it possible to show convergence
> or divergence of  $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{3k}$ by using comparison with $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}?$

What I tried:

If $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$ diverges (using Harmonic series sum) then $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$ also diverges.

But I did not understand how I could use comparison test here.
Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum u_n , \sum v_n $ are with positive terms.

Now if $\lim \frac{u_n}{v_n} = l $ where , $l$ is non zero finite number.

Then , $\sum u_n , \sum v_n $ converge or diverge together,  all of these is the rule of comparison test (limit form) .

And easily ,we can use it.

Comment: Thanks A learner got it. I have one doubt... If $0<u_{n}<v_{n}$ and $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}v_{n}$ diverges. Then can we say that $\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}u_{n}$ Diverges using limit camparison test.

Comment: No you can't. Take $\sum \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ that converges and $\sum \dfrac{1}{k} $ that diverges. And notice that $\forall k>1, 0<1/k^2 < 1/k$.

Comment: Under your hypotheses, if $\displaystyle \sum v_n$ converges then $\displaystyle \sum u_n$ converges.  And if $\displaystyle \sum u_n$ diverges then $\displaystyle \sum v_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

@A learner gave you a solution directly using the comparison test. Another way,

---

$${\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3k}}$$

Looking at the partial sums,

$${\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3k}=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{H_n}{3}}$$

Where ${H_n}$ is used here to represent the ${n^{th}}$ partial sum of the Harmonic Series. Now just argue that ${H_n}$ increases without bound (it diverges to infinity) and so the partial sums for ${\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3k}=\frac{H_n}{3}}$ must also diverge